# Django: AppRegistryNotReady when importing @wraps

Tags: python, django

I receive the following error when using `wraps`.

```
File "/Users/Marc/.local/share/virtualenvs/lumis-vJ5Odiz7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/Marc/.local/share/virtualenvs/lumis-vJ5Odiz7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Users/Marc/.local/share/virtualenvs/lumis-vJ5Odiz7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 106, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/Users/Marc/.local/share/virtualenvs/lumis-vJ5Odiz7/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/Marc/Desktop/Dev/lumis/config/settings/local_marc.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .local import *
  File "/Users/Marc/Desktop/Dev/lumis/config/settings/local.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base import *
  File "/Users/Marc/Desktop/Dev/lumis/config/settings/base.py", line 6, in <module>
    from lumis.core.helpers import get_env_variable
  File "/Users/Marc/Desktop/Dev/lumis/lumis/core/helpers.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .decorators import check_if_mixpanel_defined_in_settings
  File "/Users/Marc/Desktop/Dev/lumis/lumis/core/decorators.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.views import redirect_to_login
  File "/Users/Marc/.local/share/virtualenvs/lumis-vJ5Odiz7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import (
  File "/Users/Marc/.local/share/virtualenvs/lumis-vJ5Odiz7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/Users/Marc/.local/share/virtualenvs/lumis-vJ5Odiz7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Users/Marc/.local/share/virtualenvs/lumis-vJ5Odiz7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Users/Marc/.local/share/virtualenvs/lumis-vJ5Odiz7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 100, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/Users/Marc/.local/share/virtualenvs/lumis-vJ5Odiz7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 244, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/Users/Marc/.local/share/virtualenvs/lumis-vJ5Odiz7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 127, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Attached the decorator, where I am using the wraps function.

```
from functools import wraps

def check_if_mixpanel_defined_in_settings(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if settings.MIXPANEL_ID:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            print("Check for settings.MIXPANEL_ID failed.")
    return wrapper
```

decorators.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import redirect_to_login
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from functools import wraps
from django.conf import settings


def admin_permission_required(view_func):
    """
    A view decorator that ensures that the user is logged in
    and has access to the organizer in the request.
    If the user is not logged in, he will be redirected to
    the login page with the matching next parameter.
    If the user does not have permission for the organizer
    a PermissionDenied exception is raised.
    """
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Make sure that this decorator is only used if the organizer object exists in the request
        assert hasattr(request, 'organizer'), (
            "The admin_permission_required decorator "
            "requires the organizer object in the request."
        )

        # Check if the user is authenticated
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect_to_login(request.get_full_path())

        # Check if the user belongs to the organizer
        if request.organizer.user == request.user:
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

        raise PermissionDenied("You don't have permissions for this organizer.")
    return wrapper


class AdminPermissionRequiredMixin:
    """
    Mixin to use the admin_permission_required decorator in a class-based view.
    """
    @classmethod
    def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):
        view = super().as_view(**initkwargs)
        return admin_permission_required(view)


def check_if_mixpanel_defined_in_settings(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if settings.MIXPANEL_ID:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            print("Check for settings.MIXPANEL_ID failed.")
    return wrapper
```

Comment: You say you *receive the error when using `wraps`* - does that mean that you don't get the error if you remove the `@wraps(func)` line? Please show the full `decorators.py`.

Comment: Yes exactly. When I remove it the error doesn't appear. I'll attach the full decorators.py

Comment: I'm curious -- where are you using that decorator? It seems like a funny thing to check at runtime when the view is accessed, rather than, say, a [system check](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/checks/) that you run before deploying.

Comment: I'm using it to track Mixpanel events:
@check_if_mixpanel_defined_in_settings
def mp_track_event(user_id, event, property=None):
    mp = Mixpanel(settings.MIXPANEL_ID)
    mp.track(user_id, event, property)

Comment: It looks like you have a circular import. You could try moving ` get_env_variable` outside of `lumis.core.helpers`.